# php json response empty

Tags: php, json

My android app is hitting my api with following code

```
<?php
$token = $_GET['token'];
$encrypted_data = base64_encode($token);
$sendUrl = "https://example.com";
$url = "$sendUrl?token=$token";
$result = file_get_contents($url);
$data_array = json_decode($result, true);
$data_array['url'] = 'https://example2.com/';
$result = json_encode($data_array);
$arr = json_decode($result, true);
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES), "\n";
?>
```

My app waits for 200 response and JSON output received from $senUrl but instead its getting empty 200 response with JSON. 
How could I send JSON and wait for $sendUrl to respond before sending 200

Comment: Try to `echo` the contents of `$result` after the first `file_get_contents()` call.